# Writing to a text file through the CMD window and a C exe?

Tags: c, file, text, cmd

I was wondering how I can get this code to overwrite a textfile from it's text value to it's ASCII value.

I want it to do something like this:

CMD > c:\users\username\desktop>cA5.exe content.txt

content.txt has "abc" in it and I want the command line to change the "abc" to it's ASCII values. 97... etc. I don't want anything written in the command window, I want it to change in the text file. Is this possible, if so, how could I do it with this existing code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc[1], char *argv[1])
{

    FILE *fp; // declaring variable 


    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");


    if (fp != NULL) // checks the return value from fopen
    {
        int i;
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fp);     // scans the file 
            printf("%c",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(i!=-1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file?

Comment: Yeah, how I would overwrite any existing text with it's ASCII values.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Both of your questions in the past few minutes have been pretty basic c. Is this homework? If so, you really should be putting more effort into figuring things out for yourself; you'll learn much more that way.

Comment: Nope, it's not homework. It's just me wanting to figure out how to do things. Youtubing and other forum questions weren't really helping me understand it, so I came here. I just want to learn C :p

Comment: I tried changing "%c" to "%d" and it displays the ASCII values in the console window, I just wanted to know what you guys would try.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the "fprintf" function to write to a file. Here is a simple example, that should do what you need: http://www.elook.org/programming/c/fprintf.html. It works similar to printf, but you still need to do the conversion to ascii on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best code but very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convertToAHex(char *data, long int size, FILE *file){
    rewind(file);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        fprintf(file, "%d ", data[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if(file){
        char *data;
        long int size;

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(file);
        rewind(file);
        data = (char *) calloc(size, sizeof(char));
        if(data){
            fread(data, 1, size, file);
            convertToAHex(data, size, file);
            free(data);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```